# url for images not rendering when using template literals and Tailwind css

Tags: reactjs, tailwind-css, fetch-api, template-literals, tailwind-ui

I used template literals to pass down fetched urls from my database to my react frontend, however, images don't g et rendered, only when I hard code the URL directly, here is my code:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
const Dotw = () => {
 const [driverHero, setDriverHero] = useState("");
useEffect(() => {
    const fetchData = async () => {
      const result = await fetch(URL);
      result.json().then((data) => {
        console.log(data)
      
        setDriverHero(data.heroImage);
  
      });
    };
    fetchData();
  }, []);

  return (
 
      <div className={`w-full h-40 md:h-96 lg:h-96 max-w-screen-lg bg-no-repeat bg-cover bg-center lg:bg-center bg-[url('${driverHero}')]`}></div>
     
  );
};

export default Dotw;
```

it displays correcly on the console:

it works when I use an img tag and set the src as the driverHero state but doesn't provide the same UI when used as background image instead

Comment: console code:<div class="w-full h-40 md:h-96 lg:h-96 max-w-screen-lg bg-no-repeat bg-cover bg-center lg:bg-center bg-[url('https://i.imgur.com/DeXsw1F.jpeg')]"></div>

Answer (score 1):

> The most important implication of how Tailwind extracts class names is that it will only find classes that exist as complete unbroken strings in your source files.
>
> If you use string interpolation or concatenate partial class names together, Tailwind will not find them and therefore will not generate the corresponding CSS.

[Dynamic class names in Tailwind](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/content-configuration#dynamic-class-names)

I would suggest putting the background in the style prop of the div like so:

```
<div
  className={`w-full h-40 md:h-96 lg:h-96 max-w-screen-lg bg-no-repeat bg-cover bg-center lg:bg-center`}
  style={{backgroundImage: `url(${driverHero})`}}
></div>
```